# How do i combine two text field

Tags: android

I need help with combining two text view to complete my spelling bee interface. As shown below my underscore and the text it separated with a huge gap. What can i do to merge them? [image]

As requested below contains my xml codes for the text view. I put them both in a linear layout to try to center them both together. The only problem seems to be only the gap.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSound"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <TextView android:text="@string/randomwords" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RandomWords"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSound"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/lblUnderscore"
        android:gravity="top" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer FOUND!! Using FRAMELAYOUT.

[image]

It's close but not perfect.

[image]

Comment: yes, this cant be answered without knowing at least the type of layout

Comment: If you want superimposed `TextView`, why not use `FrameLayout` ?

Comment: Cool it looks good now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just switching to a relative layout and adding a layout_below should fix things:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSound"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <TextView android:text="@string/randomwords"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RandomWords"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSound"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_below="@id/RandomWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/lblUnderscore"
        android:gravity="top" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You could also put the underlines first (so it ends up behind) and on the randomwords use layout_bottom to get the letters to overline the underscores slightly if thats what you want

Comment: What didnt work? what did it do? Is there more in this layout you havent included?

Answer (score 0):

How about do like this with one textview?

```
Textview tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.randomwords);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(test("prospective")));
```

.............

```
public String test(String str) {
    char [] charArr = str.toCharArray();
    String htmlStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
        htmlStr += "<u>" + charArr[i] + "</u>"+" ";
    }
    return htmlStr;
}
```